# why are object addresses always 8 hex digits?

Tags: python

Examples :

0xb6f99cec

0xb6f99d2c

0xb6f99d6c

0xb6f99dac

Is it a design decision, is it a memory issue, does it make something easier, why 8 and not 4 or 12 or 16?

Comment: *Why are object addresses always 8 hex digits?* They aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory - you have 32-bit system.
On a 64-bit system, the addresses have 16 (or fewer, as I see ;-)) hexadecimal digits. Like this:

```
str(object())
Out[1]: '<object object at 0x7fe72a054360>'
```

Answer (score 4):

Each hexadecimal digit carries 4 bits of information. You have eight hexadecimal digits. Therefore, the number carries 32 bits of information. It just happens that the address fits in 32 bits. If you are using a 32-bit Python, this will always be the case; if you are using a 64-bit Python, it could be that the address *just happened* to have all high bits zero and ended up fitting into 32 bits.

Comment: You sure thats bits and not bytes?

Comment: @jason: Yes, I do mean bits.

Comment: Ahh hex F = 1111 yeah bits for some reason I thought F was 16 bits